# why Visual Studio 2012 wpf designer is blank?

Tags: wpf-controls

Why Visual Studio 2012 wpf designer blank in design time but in runtime worked correctly?

In Visual studio 2010 it worked correctly both runtime and design time.

Comment: Can you perhaps give some more detail in regards to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is unreasonable as both Windows in both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 are predominantly white (blank) and they both work in both design- and runtime.